# Understanding the generation of ntree in a k fold cross validation

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, cross-validation, decision-tree

I am trying to understand how the Random forest model works in K fold cross validation. A simple algorithm is defined according to the elements below:

1. Decide on the number of folds you want (k)
2. Subdivide your dataset into k folds
3. Use k-1 folds for a training set to build the model
4. Use the testing set to estimate statistics about the error in your tree.
5. Save your results for later
6. Repeat steps 3-6 for k times leaving out a different fold for your test set.
7. Average the errors across your iterations to predict the overall error

What I don't understand is at what level the ntree parameter intervenes. ntree being the number of trees to build. If I choose for example a ntree = 500 is it to say that at each k-1 fold, 500 new trees are built ? and are these trees different from the previous k-1 fold ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Comment: That said, the answer to both your questions is *yes*: for each one of the K folds a full model is built (here with 500 trees), and each model is independent of the rest (i.e. built from scratch every time).

Comment: Having fit a model with a 10 fold cross validation according to what you said, we will have an evaluation of the performance of 10 independent models. For a prediction for example which one is finally used? or is it the whole?

Comment: CV is not for building a single model that will be subsequently used for predictions; it is for assessing the performance of a "model" in the sense of a particular combination of parameters (like `ntree` here). Once such a satisfactory combination has been found, the model is refitted with all the training data, and that is your final model which will be subsequently used for predictions.